# A cartesian product of distributive lattices is distibutive

Tags: reference-request, lattice-orders

I have seen a few articles cite this result as coming from the 3rd edition of G Birkhoff's "Lattice theory" but I can't find the result in there myself.

The index does not seem to mention "product"s and the pdf copy I have is not searchable.

If anyone happens to know of a page number for this result in Birkhoff's book or another text I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that obvious from the definitions?

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes--see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it on page 12:

"Any direct product of distributive lattices is distributive."

This is easy to check from the definitions of meet and join in a product:
$$(x_1, x_2) \land (y_1, y_2) = (x_1 \land y_1, x_2 \land y_2)$$ and $$(x_1, x_2) \lor (y_1, y_2) = (x_1 \lor y_1, x_2 \lor y_2)$$
We have
\begin{align*}
& (x_1, x_2) \land ((y_1, y_2) \lor (z_1, z_2))  \\
&= (x_1,x_2) \land (y_1 \lor z_1,  y_2 \lor z_2) \\
&= (x_1 \land (y_1 \lor z_1), x_2 \land (y_2 \lor z_2) ) \\
&= ((x_1 \land y_1) \lor (x_1 \land z_1)), (x_2 \land y_2) \lor (x_2 \land z_2) )\\
&= (x_1 \land y_1, x_2 \land y_2) \lor  (x_1 \land z_1, x_2 \land z_2 )\\
&= ( (x_1, x_2) \land (y_1, y_2)) \lor ((x_1, x_2) \land (z_1, z_2))  
\end{align*}

Comment: It's not a matter of being obvious. It's about applying the definition of the operations in the product (coordinate-wise) and then using the fact that each factor is distributive to prove that so is the product. Perhaps you should do that once. Perhaps here, by editing this answer.

Comment: @amrsa good idea

Comment: This is good (+1), but you can generalize from the direct product of two distributive lattices to the one of any family of them (finite or infinite), that is, given a family of distributive lattices $(L_i)_{i\in I}$, and elements $a_i, b_i, c_i \in L_i$, we have $$(a_i)_{i\in I} \wedge ((b_i)_{i\in I} \vee (c_i)_{i\in I})=((a_i)_{i\in I} \wedge (b_i)_{i\in I}) \vee ((a_i)_{i\in I} \wedge (c_i)_{i\in I}).$$